# How to insert multiple rows in sql command line argument like GUI..Enter the customer name ,age and so on

Tags: sql

Without using that Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> ( Column1, Column2 )
VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value3, Value4 )
```

Comment: You'll need to elaborate further on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

We create applications using various programming languages like java, php etc. to add an interface between the user and the database. You can create a simple app using languages like Java that takes fields like name and age as input and store it in the database. In such a case, you need to enter a query once in your program and rest the application will do.